# Proof that $s_n \geq a \implies \lim s_n \geq a$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

I've been working through a proof of this following theorem in Ross's Real Analysis textbook, and was hoping someone could look this over.

Theorem. If the sequence, $s_n$, converges, and if $s_n \geq a$ for all but finitely many $n$, then $\lim s_n \geq a$.

Proof. Let $\lim s_n = s$, and assume that $s_n \geq a$ for all but finitely many $n$. Then, assume further, to establish the logically equivalent contrapositive of this theorem, that $\lim s_n < a$. Since $\lim s_n = s$, we have that 
\begin{equation}
\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n > N, \left \lvert s_n - s \right \rvert < \epsilon.
\end{equation}
Let's choose $N$ so that $\left \lvert s_n - s \right \rvert < - s + a$. This implies that $s - a < s_n - s < - s + a$, and thus that $s_n < a$. Therefore, $\lim s_n \geq a$.

How does this look?

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: What do you mean by : "$s_n\geq a$ for all but finitely many $n$" The sentence is just a contradiction itself...

Comment: This was the same terminology used in the book. I think it's saying this holds, say, for all $n > N$. Otherwise, the limit definition wouldn't accomplish much.

Comment: It is quite correct, except it's really a proof by *contrapositive*, not by contradiction: you proved that if the limit is $<a$, all $s_n$ but finitely many are $<a$.

Comment: This is a very good point. I wondered where the $\lim s_n$ assumption really came in, but I suppose it really isn't needed if this is framed as a proof by contrapositive. Thank you -- I'll edit the first post.

Comment: @Matt.P : Strange... I really don't understand this sentence : If $s_n\geq a$ for all $n$, then $s_n\geq a$ for only finitely many $n$ won't be true, and conversely, if $s_n\geq a$ for only finitely many $n$, it won't be true for all $n$... I really don't understand this sentence...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following proof by contradiction.

Let $s$ be the limit of $s_n$, to prove $s \geq a$, assume its contrary $s < a$. In this case, take $\varepsilon_0 = a - s > 0$ (fixed positive!), then for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, it follows that
$$|s_n - s| \geq s_n - s = s_n - a + a - s \geq 0 + \varepsilon_0 = \varepsilon_0,$$

which is clearly in contradiction to $\lim_n s_n = s$. This completes the proof.